# Direct all storage requirement to usb drive

Tags: raspbian, usb, storage, pip

I've mounted a usb drive. I'm attempting to exclusively use this drive for installations and execution of programs. If I pip install and execute programs from the same drive will no space will be utilized on sd card ? If not how to exclusively utilize a mounted drive in order to save space on sd card, is this possible ?

Answer (score -1):

This guide for copying the OS to harddrive worked for me : https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: Please see http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/839/5538